# I want to implement Sliding Menu using ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

Is any code or article available then please give me solutions.

I want to implement on this link: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

but i am getting error.

So any one knows this solution, then please help me.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: just give me your error details, check you added library project to demo or not properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the link you gave.

> **Setup with ActionBarSherlock**
>
> - Checkout a clean copy of ActionBarSherlock and import into your    Eclipse workspace.
> - Add ActionBarSherlock as a dependency to SlidingMenu.
> - Go into the SlidingActivities that you plan on using make them extend    Sherlock__*Activity instead of _*_Activity.

I've implemented it myself, and you just have to go into the library project and change their extend class.